# Can somebody provide the Parjanya sukta with English translation?

Tags: vedas, translation-request, resource

I want the mantras (Sanskrit) and English translation of Parjanya sukta(mantras which will bring rain). Can somebody provide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Parjanya Sukta**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv05083.htm)  is found in Rig-Veda Mandala 5 – Sukta no. 83 .

> Rishi – Atri-Bhauma  |   Devata –Parjanya | Chhanda –Tristupa ;2-4
>   –Jagati ; 9 Anustupa.

The renowned Rish Atri Bhauma, composed a prayer that the Vedic people  would have offered to invoke Parjanya .

This Sukta welcomes Rain OR Parjanya  with adoration praise. In this sukta Parjanya is said to be the driving force behind germination of seeds in plants . Its said that with the arrival of the rain plants assume different colors. The earth becomes productive due to it and then  nourishes &  feed  all living creatures. Its quite interesting to know that , here in this Sukta    lightning is said to be the cause of creation of life force in seeds . This Sukta also pray for abundance of rain , so that rivers could flow . Also at the end , after good rain this sukta prays  rain god to stop pouring excess water. So it’s a complete and beautiful Hymn describing necessary of rain for the living beings  and also the  rainy season.

Here you can also read this sukta with [**Hindi translation**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v5.104) - Below  is the Sukta.

> अछा वद तवसं गीर्भिर आभि सतुहि पर्जन्यं नमसा विवास | 
>  कनिक्रदद
>   वर्षभो जीरदानू रेतो दधात्य ओषधीषु गर्भम || 1|| 
>  वि वर्क्षान हन्त्य
>   उत हन्ति रक्षसो विश्वम बिभाय भुवनम महावधात | 
>  उतानागा ईषते
>   वर्ष्ण्यावतो यत पर्जन्य सतनयन हन्ति दुष्क्र्तः ||2||
>   रथीव
>   कशयाश्वां अभिक्षिपन्न आविर दूतान कर्णुते वर्ष्य्रं अह | 
>  दूरात
>   सिंहस्य सतनथा उद ईरते यत पर्जन्यः कर्णुते वर्ष्यं नभः |3||
>  पर वाता
>   वान्ति पतयन्ति विद्युत उद ओषधीर जिहते पिन्वते सवः | 
>  इरा विश्वस्मै
>   भुवनाय जायते यत पर्जन्यः पर्थिवीं रेतसावति ||4|| 
>  यस्य वरते
>   पर्थिवी नन्नमीति यस्य वरते शफवज जर्भुरीति | 
>  यस्य वरत ओषधीर
>   विश्वरूपाः स नः पर्जन्य महि शर्म यछ || 5||
>  दिवो नो वर्ष्टिम मरुतो
>   ररीध्वम पर पिन्वत वर्ष्णो अश्वस्य धाराः | 
>  अर्वाङ एतेन
>   सतनयित्नुनेह्य अपो निषिञ्चन्न असुरः पिता नः || 6||
>  अभि करन्द सतनय
>   गर्भम आ धा उदन्वता परि दीया रथेन | 
>  दर्तिं सु कर्ष विषितं नयञ्चं
>   समा भवन्तूद्वतो निपादाः || 7||
>  महान्तं कोशम उद अचा नि षिञ्च
>   सयन्दन्तां कुल्या विषिताः पुरस्तात | 
>  घर्तेन दयावाप्र्थिवी वय
>   उन्धि सुप्रपाणम भवत्व अघ्न्याभ्यः ||8||
>  यत पर्जन्य कनिक्रदत सतनयन
>   हंसि दुष्क्र्तः | 
>  परतीदं विश्वम मोदते यत किं च पर्थिव्याम अधि
>   ||9||
>  अवर्षीर वर्षम उद उ षू गर्भायाकर धन्वान्य अत्येतवा उ | 
>   अजीजन ओषधीर भोजनाय कम उत परजाभ्यो ऽविदो मनीषाम ||10||
>
> achā vada tavasaṃ ghīrbhir ābhi stuhi parjanyaṃ namasā vivāsa | 
>   kanikradad vṛṣabho jīradānū reto dadhāty oṣadhīṣu gharbham || 
>  vi
>   vṛkṣān hanty uta hanti rakṣaso viśvam bibhāya bhuvanam mahāvadhāt |
>   
>  utānāghā īṣate vṛṣṇyāvato yat parjanya stanayan hanti duṣkṛtaḥ ||
>   
>  rathīva kaśayāśvāṃ abhikṣipann āvir dūtān kṛṇute varṣyṛṃ aha |
>   
>  dūrāt siṃhasya stanathā ud īrate yat parjanyaḥ kṛṇute varṣyaṃ
>   nabhaḥ ||  pra vātā vānti patayanti vidyuta ud oṣadhīr jihate pinvate
>   svaḥ | 
>  irā viśvasmai bhuvanāya jāyate yat parjanyaḥ pṛthivīṃ
>   retasāvati || 
>  yasya vrate pṛthivī nannamīti yasya vrate śaphavaj
>   jarbhurīti | 
>  yasya vrata oṣadhīr viśvarūpāḥ sa naḥ parjanya mahi
>   śarma yacha || 
>  divo no vṛṣṭim maruto rarīdhvam pra pinvata vṛṣṇo
>   aśvasya dhārāḥ | 
>  arvāṅ etena stanayitnunehy apo niṣiñcann asuraḥ
>   pitā naḥ || 
>  abhi kranda stanaya gharbham ā dhā udanvatā pari dīyā
>   rathena | 
>  dṛtiṃ su karṣa viṣitaṃ nyañcaṃ samā bhavantūdvato
>   nipādāḥ || 
>  mahāntaṃ kośam ud acā ni ṣiñca syandantāṃ kulyā
>   viṣitāḥ purastāt | 
>  ghṛtena dyāvāpṛthivī vy undhi suprapāṇam
>   bhavatv aghnyābhyaḥ || 
>  yat parjanya kanikradat stanayan haṃsi
>   duṣkṛtaḥ | 
>  pratīdaṃ viśvam modate yat kiṃ ca pṛthivyām adhi ||
>   
>  avarṣīr varṣam ud u ṣū ghṛbhāyākar dhanvāny atyetavā u | 
>   ajījana oṣadhīr bhojanāya kam uta prajābhyo 'vido manīṣām ||
>
> **1** SING with these songs thy welcome to the Mighty, with adoration praise and call Parjanya. The Bull, loud roaring, swift to send his
>   bounty, lays in the plants the seed. for germination.
>   **2** He smites the trees apart, he slays the demons: all life fears him who wields the mighty weapon. From him exceeding strong fices e’en
>   the guiltless, when thundering Parjanya smites the wicked.
>   **3** Like a car-driver whipping on his horses, he makes the messengers of rain spring forward. Far off resounds the roaring of the
>   lion, what time Parjanya fills the sky with rain-cloud.
>   **4** Forth burst the winds, down come the lightning-flashes: the plants shoot up, the realm of light is streaming. Food springs
>   abundant for all living creatures, what time Parjanya quickens earth
>   with moisture.
>   **5** Thou at whose bidding earth bows low before thee, at whose command hoofed cattle fly in terror, At whose behest the plants assume
>   all colours, even thou Parjanya, yield us great protection.
>   **6** Send down for us the rain of heaven, ye Maruts, and let the Stallion's flood descend in torrents. Come hither with this thunder
>   while thou pourest the waters down, our heavenly Lord and Father.
>   **7** Thunder and roar: the germ of life deposit. Fly round us on thy chariot waterladen.
>  Thine opened water-skin draw with thee
>   downward, and let the hollows and the heights be level.
>   **8** Lift up the mighty vessel, pour down water, and let the liberated streams rush forward.
>  Saturate both the earth and heaven
>   with fatness, and for the cows let there be drink abundant.
>   **9** When thou, with thunder and with roar, Parjanya, smitest sinners down, This universe exults thereat, yea, all that is upon the earth.
>   **10** Thou hast poured down the rain-flood now withhold it. Thou hast made desert places fit for travel. Thou hast made herbs to grow for
>   our enjoyment: yea, thou hast won thee praise from living creatures.

Comment: Only one Parjanya Sukta is there in the entire Rig Veda?

Comment: This is the Parjanya Sukta which you enquired in the question which is , used  to invoke Parjanya .But I will update the answer with the  other similar suktas with devata parjanya if found.